# Create recovery medium from Windows 7 recovery partition

Tags: command-line, partition, hard-disk, data-recovery

Many laptops are delivered with `Windows 7` recovery partition (but without CD or DVD) which takes place on the harddrive that could contain some Linux distribution or serve for data storage.

I don't want to format it because sister paid for this partition and has a license key. But she would like to backup it to some medium and use it in time she will need to use this system.

Is there a command in Linux that will backup this recovery partition or make a bootable DVD from this partition?

Note: The content of the partition is not so important. Important is to make a backup of this partition to some medium (best would be CD or DVD) and show how to restore from that medium.

Comment: How big is the partition? Please post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `parted -l /dev/sda` -- assuming `/dev/sda` is your disk.

Comment: I don't have the laptop at home now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tar` and `gzip` is probably your best bet. You *could* use `dd` to do a block-by-block copy of it but this will obviously give you a file exactly the same size as the partition.

Assuming the partition is `/dev/sda2`, something like:-

```
mkdir /mnt/recovery
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /mnt/recovery
cd /mnt/recovery
tar -cvf - . | gzip -c >/path/to/store/recovery.tar.gz
```

should back it up, and:-

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda2
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /mnt/recovery
cd /mnt/recovery
tar xvf /path/to/sotre/recovery.tar.gz
```

to put it all back again.

Comment: This makes sense. And what if the partition `/dev/sda2` does not exist before recovery? I have to create a partition that is little larger than the extracted archive?

Comment: Yup - that should be fine. I was assuming the partition still existed but recreating one should be fine.